# Json property of an undefined object not printing. Why?

Tags: javascript, undefined, json

I came around a simple behavior that I cannot quite understand. I am trying to check for the validity of a JSON array of objects, the core point here is that the user 'choses' its size (for example, if he types **2**, there will be **2 objects**).

Each object is supposed to have a name and a version.

I wanted to be sure that he enters something, so when he hits he submit button, I'm checking for this kind of statement:

```
if (myarray[0].name !== undefined || myarray.name !== null)
{
  // Do some crazy stuff as crazy a return;
}
```

And I was not working. When I went to further inspection (console.log, wow), I noticed this:

```
console.log(myarray);         // Prints '[]' because it is empty
console.log(myarray[0]);      // Prints 'undefined', seems legit
console.log(myarray[0].name); // Prints ... Well, nothing
```

---

Why does the third `console.log` does not print `undefined` ? Any property of an undefined object should be `undefined`, or is there something I am missing in JavaScript ?

Thank you in advance !

Comment: JSON is a *textual notation* for data exchange. [(More)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2904181/157247) If you're working in JavaScript source code, and not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why does the third `console.log` does not print `undefined` ?

Because it throws an exception: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined`. That happens when you try to read a property from `undefined` or `null`.

Comment: Silly, stupid me. I need some sleep. Thanks. I'll validate asap.